# Dynamic form with Spreadsheets and apps-script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I'm trying to create a volunteer signup form for a special needs program.

Aim of this form is to take a spreadsheet with the schedule information of riders and times for a given week and update the corresponding column for [Day, Student] with volunteer name. 
Fields are

1. Volunteer name
2. Day
3. Student

A student has maximum of one class per Day.

Based on the day you select, I would like to give a set of Students for that Day. I want to populate the Student Choices based on the Day Selected.

A lot of the volunteering folks are not very adept at using computers so this seems to be the simplest way of capturing a volunteers interest for a given [Day, Student].

[ItemResponse](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item-response) gives me a way of accessing the response to each question, can this be done in realtime while the form is being filled s the question.

Is this possible? 
I'am going to test this soon but any pointers would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: It's possible, but you probably won't get any code written for it here on Stack Overflow.  Your question is "Off Topic" to Stack Overflow.  It's not a good question for Stack Overflow.  A Google Form can't dynamically change drop down list choices after the Form has been loaded.  A Google Form can be programatically designed before it is opened, but it's not very easy.  And you might need to have a different Form file for each person filling out the Form.  You could use a Web App.  Of course all of this depends upon the skill level of the person working on this project.

Comment: That pretty much answers my question. My initial thoughts were that it cannot be done. I have a basic script that takes spreadsheet values and creates forms. Its my first time ever dealing with google-apps so pardon my ignorance, but I don't understand why you think this is off topic or not a good question for Stack Overflow. Appreciate your time and effort.

Comment: And FYI I can write my own code. I did not write that question to get people to write code for me, just wanted to know if "it is possible"?  apps-script isn't an unconstrained platform so pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: The reason I think it's off topic is because of the guidelines created by Stack Overflow.  You could suggest that they change the guidelines and see what happens.

Comment: I would not say that it's impossible.  I think you could easily accomplish what you desire with a html based form using a webapp.  Since you write your own code  it should be easy for you to create multipage webapp.  I've also found that the new AppMaker is also fun to use.  Since you know appsscript you'll find it fairly easy to come up to speed with AppMaker and it makes creating a multipage app even easier.  Of course, you will have to go with a Google Business Account to get it at the current time.

Comment: This is more than helpful, I will dig into AppMaker. Google business account shouldn't be a hindrance.thanks for the pointers @Cooper

Comment: @Sandy Good you seem to be a respectable developer for  Google suite and JavaScript in general, I respect your contributions on here.  if you don't like my question down voting is an option that SO provides. I'd think you knew this considering your expertise with stack overflow

Comment: @sainathreddy Down voting costs me points.  I don't want to give up any points.  I don't blame you for taking this personally, if that is the case.  It would bother me also.  But there is a reason for the rules as they are, and I respect the reasons for them.

Comment: @SandyGood Only downvoting answers will cost you points, downvoting questions is free.

Comment: I did not know that down-voting questions is free.  That's awesome!